# How to create a Windows Phone app that parses html data from a website

Tags: javascript, html, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

I'm planning to create a Windows Phone App for my own site (still not up and running).

I don't know how to go about it.
What I know is that I don't want to use the webview control as it would make the app primitive and ugly.

I am thinking of downloading the html content and parsing it into XAML elements to build the app controls.

But, I am a beginner developer and have no experience in this. If anyone could guide me on how to proceed further it would be very helpful.

Comment: You might want to ask this on http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can just create hosted web app,just wrapping web to windows app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used AngleSharp to parse html and construct XAML elements based on that.
https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp

Answer (score 1):

> "I am thinking of downloading the html content and parsing it into XAML elements to build the app controls."

Hell, no!

In my opinion this is the way you should go: your current web app should have calls to services which provide you the data you need to display on the UI. Your web app is a client. Another client could be the Windows Mobile app.

Windows Store apps can be developed using HTML5+JS or C#+XAML. Pick one way, you know best.

Just saying, if you have some REST service behind everything, it will help you out build clients with ease.

Answer (score 0):

"I don't want to use the webview control as it would make the app primitive"

This is that you believe. It's possible it's because you have not knowledge enough.

You can make beautiful apps with html. More this if your are trying only make a web as app.

Try making php get_contents and calling that from ajax. Into the app you can style the data you parsed

Answer (score 0):

If you have web application, you have two easy ways to convert it to mobile:

1. [Cordova](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/cordova-vs.aspx)
2. [Hosted Web App](https://microsoftedge.github.io/WebAppsDocs/en-US/win10/CreateHWA.htm?WT.mc_id=16585-DEV-codeproject-article70)

But Cordova uses webview, so probably you want to use second option:

You can create app by wrapping existing web site:

> Click “File -> New Project” and choose “JavaScript -> Windows ->
>   Windows Universal -> Blank App (Windows Universal)”

I think it's much easier than designing XAML application.